# How can i make a subtraction if one cell in sheet is not equal to 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will help me to make a simple subtraction in excel sheet.
In one column i have values 0,2,3,4 and i want to only make subtraction with another column when there is not a 0 value. Can you help please?

Comment: What have you tried, yourself?  The idea behind StackOverflow is that you give it a try and ask here if you have any issues.  So, here are the basic building blocks: [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), [mathematical functions](https://www.exceldemy.com/adding-and-subtracting-in-excel-in-one-formula/), now head off and have a go!

Comment: Of course i was trying to do it with COUNTIF, SUMIF functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel offers the possibility in a formula only to do something "IF" a condition is met, using the `IF()` formula. More information can be found under [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

You can make a formula, like this (in cell C1):

```
=IF(A1 <> 0; B1-A1;B1)
```

Which means: in case A1 is not zero, subtract it from B1 and put the result in C1, otherwise put B1 value in C1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me just perfect